# Want to change the Bottom Tabs whichever the user goes into Buyer mode or seller Mode in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

Hi there hope to do well Developer, I have been confused about my ongoing project Basically I going to build an app  ( in react native ) just like Fiverr where users can sell and purchase services. I have done most of the work but am stuck on the navigation of the Buyer and seller. Just like Fiverr, I want to show different tabs on the buyer screen and seller modes I don't know how I can do this. I have implemented the switch from where am getting the "true" to "false" results. I have stored these results in the Asynstorage and whenever I implement the check that {rolechange == true : }  then I got an Error or sometimes I got nothing.

Am also confused that I am doing it the right way. Need Help from Seniors

Comment: Please add your code, it's very difficult to help without seeing the code you're asking about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.